# Surface integral on close surface

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields, surface-integrals

Currently, I was reading this paper "Finite element methods for surface PDEs". For the theorem 2.14 in the paper:

$
\int_{\Gamma} \nabla_{\Gamma} f \cdot \nabla_{\Gamma} g \mathrm{d} A=-\int_{\Gamma} f \Delta_{\Gamma} g \mathrm{d} A+\int_{\partial \Gamma} f \nabla_{\Gamma} g \cdot \mu \mathrm{d} A
$

where $\Gamma$ is defined as a surface, $\nabla_{\Gamma}$ is the surface gradient on surface $\Gamma$, $\Delta_{\Gamma}$ is the Laplace–Beltrami operator on $\Gamma.$

My question is that, if the $\Gamma$ is a close surface, is the second term on the right hand side of the equation equals to $0$ and why?

Comment: That's not necessary true you need a boundary condition such as, tangential derivative $\nabla_{\Gamma} f $ is $0$ over $\partial \Gamma$ or  $\nabla f \times \nu = 0$ over $\partial \Gamma$ .

Comment: @PabloHerrera, Thank you for your answer. For a closed surface, is there still exist a boundary? Thats what confused me. The wiki said, there is no boudary for closed surface, so if there is no boundary, then the second term would be 0, right?

Comment: Yes, you right.